# Function Pointers with different signatures (example: optional parameter with a default value)

Tags: delphi, function-pointers, signature

Is it possible to create a function-pointer with a default parameter, something like

```
TFunctionPointer = function(sName:AnsiString; tOptional: TObject = nil):smallint;
```

What I want to achieve:

A function pointer, which can accept a function of type

```
function A(sName:AnsiString)
```

or

```
function B(sName:AnsiString, tOptional: TObject)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Default parameter is just a syntactic sugar - actually function call has two parameters.

But you can use function references and anonymous methods to create such function pointers - function adapters.

```
type
  fnA = function(const sName: AnsiString): integer;
  fnB = function(const sName: AnsiString; const tOptional: TObject); integer;

  fnRef = reference to function(const sName: AnsiString; const tOptional: TObject): integer;

  fnBridge = record 
     Bridge: fnRef;
     class operator Implicit(fn: fnA): fnBridge;
     class operator Implicit(fn: fnB): fnBridge;
  end;

class operator fnBridge.Implicit(fn: fnA): fnBridge;
begin
  Result.Bridge := 
     function(const sName: AnsiString; const tOptional: TObject): integer
     begin
       Result := fn(sName); 
     end;
end;

class operator fnBridge.Implicit(fn: fnB): fnBridge;
begin
  Result.Bridge := 
     function(const sName: AnsiString; const tOptional: TObject): integer
     begin
       Result := fn(sName, tOptional); 
     end;
end;

function A(const sName: AnsiString): integer; 
begin Result := Length(sName) end;

function B(const sName: AnsiString; const tOptional: TObject): integer; 
begin Result := Length(sName) - Length(tOptional.ClassName) end;

function Consumer (const Param1, Param2: integer; const Action: fnBridge): integer;
begin
  Result := Param1 + Param2 * Action.Bridge('ABCDE', Application);
end;

....
  ShowMessage( IntToStr( Consumer(10, 20, A) ));
  ShowMessage( IntToStr( Consumer(10, 20, B) ));
```

PS: since Delphi version was not specified it means that answer for ANY Delphi version suits fine. This method should work wit hany version starting  with Delphi 2009 and later.

PPS: references to functions with captured variables are implemented internally as `TInterfacedObject` descendants. So overall this is just a reduced case of "Strategy pattern" using "higher-order functions"

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function

Comment: Easier just to define two overloads of Consumer

Comment: @DavidHeffernan in this particular example - yes. But you know this is just a demo. I believe you understand that the topicstarter asked how to create a specific indirection/abstraction layer (and i showed the way), and that those layers are usually created for more rich combinations than two "servers" multiplied by single "client" in the demo above

Comment: What do you mean by that exactly, @DavidHeffernan ? Could you provide an example pls?

Comment: @Arioch'The Actually what I have in mind is simpler in all cases.

Comment: @skylla I added a simple example to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible. In order for a function to be of type `TFunctionPointer`, it must declare two parameters.

A default parameter is still a parameter. Your `TFunctionPointer` is a function with two parameters. When you call it and supply only one parameter, the compiler supplies the default parameter at the call site. So two parameters are still passed to the function.

To expand on this. Consider the following:

```
procedure Foo(Bar: Integer=666);
begin
end;
```

When you call the procedure like this:

```
Foo();
```

it looks as though the procedure has no parameters. But that is not the case. The compiler translates your code into this:

```
Foo(666);
```

The conclusion is that if you want to allow receipt of functions with different numbers of parameters, you'll need to provide an explicit mechanism to receive those different function types. For instance:

```
procedure DoSomething(const Callback: TProc<string, TObject>); overload;
begin
  Callback(str, obj);
end;

procedure DoSomething(const Callback: TProc<string>); overload;
begin
  DoSomething(
    procedure(arg1: string; arg2: TObject)
    begin
      Callback(arg1);
    end
  );
end;
```

Comment: Well, i cannot see how is it different from what i told about your suggestion. And the counter-example is the same: increase number of clients. *DoSomething, DoSomethingDifferent, DoSomethingElse, DoNothingAtAll...*  And increase number of client types: *TProc<xxx>, TFunc<yyy>, TFunc<zzz,www>, TProc<ttt,rrr>...* And add multiparam servers like *DoThisAndThat(..., TProc1, TProc2), CalculateThisOrThat(...,TFunc1,TFunc2,TFunc3)....* etc

Comment: @Arioch'The It's different because it has much less boilerplate. No need for the record. You also seem to think that the code in your answer scales up magically. You can support more signatures without defining extra types? It looks to me that if you want support for N signatures then you will need the following: N procedural types fn1..fnN, N class operator Implicit declarations, N class operator Implicit implementations. Or do I not understand?

Comment: True. That is O(N) scaling. It is not magical of course, but nothing is. In your case scaling would be O(N*M*K) - which would be easier in most simple use cases like this demo, but would scale much worse (if scaling is needed at all). Additionally i think we somewhat gone off-rail: the topicstarter asked about "function-pointer" so he wished to pass the reference to functions with different signatures into one and the same API via some var with fixed type. Unless using duck-typing and something like IDispatch, i cannot see how to implement it without bridge objects.

Comment: @Arioch'The Your answer went off-topic because it did not answer the direct question (answer = no) and gave code to do something else. Of course, it turned out that the user wanted a solution to the problem rather than an answer to the question. That's just me being pedantic. As for the scaling, in what what is my version `O(N*M*K)`? Scaling is same as yours.

Comment: Well, that depends upon how pedantic we gonna be about "function-pointer" term. Is C++ `SharedPtr<T>` a pointer or an object ?  Same here. // N is the same. M is the number of "consumers" - our demo only had one, but there may be many. I would need one implementation wrt record-based bridge, and you would need N implementations for each of M consumers.  Then K is average of factorials of number of "function pointer" arguments in those "consumer" functions. For example function might be some filter of objects, and consumer would diff subsets of objects from two datasets, differently filtered

Comment: @Arioch'The Now I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Add to your example what i asked above - `DoSomething(..., fnX), DoSomethingDifferent(..., fnX), DoSomethingElse(..., fnX), DoNothingAtAll(..., fnX)` and then add `DoThisAndThat(..., TProc1, TProc2), CalculateThisOrThat(...,TFunc1,TFunc2,TFunc3).... etc` withh all the permutations of mentioned types. You would see. TProcX and TFuncX are just jokers, placeholders that should be substituable by any of those *fnX* types.

Comment: @Arioch'The I'm still confused. But it looks like you are designing for future complexity that may not be needed. I actually think my answer was better before since it actually tackled the question. Now it meanders. Oh well.

Comment: "may not be needed" - yes, i told above "if scaling is needed at all". *PS. Actually my scaling is O(N+M) > O(N)* :=) Then about offtopic. I consider the last line - "How can I achieve this?" - being the question. And i answered it: i built a datatype that is "function-pointer" requested.  Whether TS's program could be structured avoiding use of "function-pointers" is beyond the scope. Whether those "function-pointers" are much more complex entities than a regular `Pointer` datatype is irrelevant i think. `SharePtr<T>` is also a complex structure, yet every1 uses them as pointers and calls so